# Is there a way to sort a list of ordered tuples of strings into a list of strings while maintaining the order of the strings in the tuples?

Tags: nltk

I have a list of tuples. Each tuples is ordered according to a string that appears before another. So for the first tuple in list ‘gi-‘ linearly proceeds ‘ba-‘.

list = [(‘gi-‘, ‘ba-‘), (‘be-‘, ‘ke-‘), (‘be-‘, ‘ba-‘), (‘gi-‘, ‘ke-‘), … ]

I am trying to make a function to give the ordered_list. Notice that I expect some strings to be unordered with respect to each other, such as ‘ke-‘ and ‘ba-‘.

ordered_list = [‘gi-‘, ‘be-‘, {‘ke-‘, ba-} … ]

I’m not sure what sorting method I would use to do this task. This is a nltk project that is similar to forming a Cinque style order of adverbs.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: def bubble_sort(list1): 

        for i in range(0,len(list1)-1):  
            for j in range(len(list1)-1):  
                if list1[i][1] != list1[j][0]: 
                    first = list1[j]  
                    list1[j] = list1[j+1]  
                    list1[j+1] = first 
        return list1

    print(bubble_sort(P))